# Choose JDK location in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to use JDK 8 in my project, but in Android Studio 4.2.1 I can't choose JDK 8 when selecting a menu item "JDK Location". A window is displayed with the message: "Please choose a valid JDK11 directory".

[displayed window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDt1q.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can still work in `Android Studio 4.2` with Java 8.

For that you don't need to change JDK

just set Java 8 compability in `app/build.gradle` file

```
android {
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

add following dependencies to `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    // JAX-B dependencies for JDK 9+
    implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2"
    implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2"
}
```

Comment: I already have these settings, but it doesn't work. In my opinion, Java 11 is still used, because the class 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBException'  cannot be loaded (he was removed in Java 11). That is, Android Studio does not use Java 8 (?)

Comment: @Nikita i could successful update android studio without changing to JAVA 11. try to `invalidate caches / restart` or rebuild the project. I still working with Java 8 in Android Studio 4.2

Comment: I've tried both (invalidate caches / restart and rebuild). This doesn't work:)

Comment: Thanks, but still 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBException'

Comment: ...and still wondering how setup jdk8, why Android Studio doesn't allow use it

Comment: read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases) _In previous releases, JDK 8 was bundled with Studio. In 4.2, however, JDK 11 is now bundled instead. When using the new bundled JDK to run Gradle, this may result in some incompatibility_ Always, before updating something -> research for changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can uninstall your jdk11 and install JDK 8 for that project to set and finally upgrade the protect to the new version with java 11 codes.